# Cannot set margin to nested grid

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm using the `Popupbox` provided by `MaterialDesignInXaml`, and I'm trying to assign to nested grid a margin of 8px, so I did:

```
<GroupBox>
  <GroupBox.Header>
   <UniformGrid Columns="2">
    <TextBlock Text="testo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
    <materialDesign:PopupBox StaysOpen="True" Grid.Column="1" 
                         Style="{StaticResource PopupBoxStyle}">
       <Grid Width="300">
       ...
       </Grid>
</materialDesign:PopupBox

<Style x:Key="PopupBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type materialDesign:PopupBox}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="8" />
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

the problem's that the header of my GroupBox will increase the height, but if I set the margin without using the `PopupBoxStyle` the header height of the GroupBox will remain the same.

How can I prevent to enalrge the height of groupbox? What mistake I did creating the `PopupBoxStyle`? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> How can I prevent to enalrge the height of groupbox?

Set the `Margin` of the `Grid` in the `ToogleContent` to `0` to override the style setter or remove the setter from the style:

```
<materialDesign:PopupBox.ToggleContent>
       <Grid Width = "300" Margin="0">
       ...
       </Grid>
</materialDesign:PopupBox.ToggleContent>
```

Comment: sorry I was wrong the grid isn't inside the toggle, check the update please

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your issue.